# Installing FX Experience Tools

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, javafx

I am building a desktop application using JavaFX, and have installed scene builder integrated with NetBeans. Now I am trying to install fx experience tool on my windows platform but getting some JRE problem.

All my NetBeans and Scene Builder with JDK 8 environment working fine only error with installing FX Experience Tool.

[image: This is the error message getting while installing tool]

[** Log File Link **](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/468119/i4j_nlog_3)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify the name of the tool, I initially assumed you were referring to ScenicView.

But you are using fxetools, I was able to install and run it on Java 1.7.0_71 under Windows 8.1.
Here's what you do:

In the directory that contains fxetools, there is a jre directory that is included (1.6.0_30).
RENAME this directory from jre to jre6.

NOW, when you start fxetools, it should look to your currently installed jre, or at least, to the jre specified by JAVA_HOME. I don't know whether the application is fully functional, but at least it should run for you now as it did for me. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO7n8.jpg

Comment: Actually fx experience tool is name for collectively Caspian Styler, Animation Spline Editor, Derived Color Calculator.

Comment: I edited my answer since my initial assumption was incorrect. You should be able to run fxetools now, using my update.